Confusion about Databricks SCC, NAT, and Internet connection (Azure)
I created an Azure Databricks workspace with the below features

Deployed in my Azure virtual network (VNet injection)
Enabled Secure cluster connectivity
Enabled the Back-end Private Link

I did not create and use a NAT. I found that I still can access Internet in a notebook with a compute.
Does it mean a NAT is not necessary in the architecture? My compute (virtual machine) does not have a public IP, how does the network traffic work from my compute to Internet?
The document Secure cluster connectivity says:
If you enable secure cluster connectivity on your workspace that uses VNet injection, Databricks recommends that your workspace has a stable egress public IP.

For deployments that need some customization, choose an Azure NAT
gateway.

Does it mean the NAT is only necessary if I want my workspace has a stable egress public IP?
Thank you.

I got the answer from Slash on Databricks Community. Thank you, Slash.
In Azure, virtual machines created in a virtual network without explicit outbound connectivity defined are assigned a default outbound public IP address. So that's why you outbound access to internet.
But take into account that in near future this feature would be retired from azure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/default-outbound-access
